# How to create an overlaying menu in glew that doesn't care about camera?

Tags: c++, windows, opengl, glew

So I have a glew project.  And I am trying to create something that is basically a "life-bar" that overlays everything.  My problem is I can not figure out how to draw it because my camera (defined as "GLFrame cameraFrame;") is moving and rotating to accommodate the players movements.  Also even if it didnt pay attention to the camera I worry it would intersect with other geometry on the level.  How can I do this in glew?

I have considered trying to get it not to intersect by using

```
glPolygonOffset(-1.0f, -1.0f);
```

but it doesn't work

Currently I am defining the life bar as two triangles.

```
GLBatch bar1;
GLfloat vSquare[6][3] 

bar1.Begin(GL_TRIANGLES, 6);
bar1.CopyVertexData3f(vSquare);
bar1.End();
```

And it draws perfectly, except just like all the other level geometry it follows the perspective of the camera.  How can I do this?

If you so desire here is the part of my code that has to do with glew and opengl

You can probably scroll down to the bottom, that is where the juicy stuff all is

```
//Platform demo code.  Copyright Caleb Kierum.  Do not reproduce without permission
#include <GLTools.h>
#include <GLMatrixStack.h>
#include <GLFrame.h>
#include <GLFrustum.h>
#include <GLBatch.h>
#include <GLGeometryTransform.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <climits>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//A functiion that will allow variables to become strings for debugging
#define SSTR( x ) dynamic_cast< std::ostringstream & >( \
        ( std::ostringstream() << std::dec << x ) ).str()

#include <math.h>
#ifdef __APPLE__
#include <glut/glut.h>
#else
#define FREEGLUT_STATIC
#include <GL/glut.h>
#endif
#define PI 3.14159265

//Shader manager thing
GLShaderManager         shaderManager;
GLMatrixStack           modelViewMatrix;
GLMatrixStack           projectionMatrix;
//Camera translation things
GLFrame                         cameraFrame;
//Object translation things
GLFrame             objectFrame;
GLFrustum                       viewFrustum;


GLBatch                         triangleBatch;
GLBatch                         QuadStrip;
GLBatch                         playerBatch;

//2d point structure
struct fPoint {
        float x;
        float y;
};

//Collision status
struct CStatus {
        bool front;
        bool right;
        bool left;
        bool back;
        bool top;
        bool bottom;
};

//Stores a 3d coord
struct Coord {
        float x;
        float y;
        float z;
};

//Stores collision info for all non rotated boxes
struct Box {
        Coord c1;
        Coord c2;
        Coord c3;
        Coord c4;
        Coord c5;
        Coord c6;
        Coord c7;
        Coord c8;
};

//Stores things an entity might need
struct Entity {
        float x;
        float y;
        float z;
        float d;
        float fd;
        CStatus collision;
        Box box;
        Box lbox;
};

//Stores 3d rotation Euler style
struct Rot {
        float x;
        float y;
        float z;
};

//Stores 3 bools
struct Bool3 {
        bool c1;
        bool c2;
        bool c3;
};

//Holds the data for a line
struct Line{
        POINT p2;
        POINT p1;
};

//Stores the color
struct Color {
        GLfloat r;
        GLfloat g;
        GLfloat b;
        GLfloat a;
};

//Allows a box to have structure and data
struct BoxD {
        Box obj;
        int c;
};

//Stores a boud of something
struct Square {
        float left;
        float right;
        float top;
        float down;
};

//Stores the current first platform slot that is empty
int current = 0;
//Maximum ammount of platforms. If more are created it will crash
const int max = 60;


GLGeometryTransform     transformPipeline;
M3DMatrix44f            shadowMatrix;

//Stores all the level geometry and the color for each
GLBatch Level[max];
GLfloat Color[max];
BoxD Collisions[max];

//store things related to the player
Entity player;

GLfloat vBlack[] = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f };
GLfloat vRed[] = { 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f };
GLfloat vOrange[] = { 1.0f, 0.67f, 0.0f, 0.5f };//
GLfloat vYellow[] = { 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f };
GLfloat vGreen[] = { 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f };
GLfloat vBlue[] = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f };
GLfloat vIndigo[] = { 0.294f, 0.0f, 0.509f, 1.0f }; //
GLfloat vViolet[] = { 0.560f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f };//
GLfloat vCol[] = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f };

//Coordinates of a pyramid debugging
GLfloat vPyramid[12][3] = { -2.0f, 0.0f, -2.0f,
                               2.0f, 0.0f, -2.0f,
                                0.0f, 4.0f, 0.0f,

                                2.0f, 0.0f, -2.0f,
                                2.0f, 0.0f, 2.0f,
                                0.0f, 4.0f, 0.0f,

                                2.0f, 0.0f, 2.0f,
                                -2.0f, 0.0f, 2.0f,
                                0.0f, 4.0f, 0.0f,

                                -2.0f, 0.0f, 2.0f,
                                -2.0f, 0.0f, -2.0f,
                                 0.0f, 4.0f, 0.0f};

float grow = 1.2;
GLfloat Playa[24][3] = { -grow, 4.0f, -grow,
        grow, 4.0f, -grow,
        grow, 4.0f, grow,
        -grow, 4.0f, grow,

        -grow, 0.0f, -grow,
        grow, 0.0f, -grow,
        grow, 0.0f, grow,
        -grow, 0.0f, grow,

        grow, 4.0f, -grow,
        grow, 4.0f, grow,
        grow, 0.0f, grow,
        grow, 0.0f, -grow,

        -grow, 4.0f, -grow,
        -grow, 4.0f, grow,
        -grow, 0.0f, grow,
        -grow, 0.0f, -grow,

        -grow, 4.0f, grow,
        grow, 4.0f, grow,
        grow, 0.0f, grow,
        -grow, 0.0f, grow,

        -grow, 4.0f, -grow,
        grow, 4.0f, -grow,
        grow, 0.0f, -grow,
        -grow, 0.0f, -grow};

//Draws the model with an edge around it
void DrawWireFramedBatch(GLBatch* pBatch, int c)
{
        switch(c)
        {
                case 1:
                        shaderManager.UseStockShader(GLT_SHADER_FLAT, transformPipeline.GetModelViewProjectionMatrix(), vRed);
                        break;
                case 2:
                        shaderManager.UseStockShader(GLT_SHADER_FLAT, transformPipeline.GetModelViewProjectionMatrix(), vOrange);
                        break;
                case 3:
                        shaderManager.UseStockShader(GLT_SHADER_FLAT, transformPipeline.GetModelViewProjectionMatrix(), vYellow);
                        break;
                case 4:
                        shaderManager.UseStockShader(GLT_SHADER_FLAT, transformPipeline.GetModelViewProjectionMatrix(), vGreen);
                        break;
                case 5:
                        shaderManager.UseStockShader(GLT_SHADER_FLAT, transformPipeline.GetModelViewProjectionMatrix(), vBlue);
                        break;
                case 6:
                        shaderManager.UseStockShader(GLT_SHADER_FLAT, transformPipeline.GetModelViewProjectionMatrix(), vIndigo);
                        break;
                case 7:
                        shaderManager.UseStockShader(GLT_SHADER_FLAT, transformPipeline.GetModelViewProjectionMatrix(), vViolet);
                        break;
        }
   // Draw the batch solid green

    pBatch->Draw();

    // Draw black outline
    glPolygonOffset(-1.0f, -1.0f);      // Shift depth values
    glEnable(GL_POLYGON_OFFSET_LINE);

    // Draw lines antialiased
    glEnable(GL_LINE_SMOOTH);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    // Draw black wireframe version of geometry
    glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);
    glLineWidth(2.5f);
    shaderManager.UseStockShader(GLT_SHADER_FLAT, transformPipeline.GetModelViewProjectionMatrix(), vBlack);
    pBatch->Draw();

    // Put everything back the way we found it
    glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL);
    glDisable(GL_POLYGON_OFFSET_LINE);
    glLineWidth(1.0f);
        glEnable(GL_MULTISAMPLE);

    }
//This happens on the start initializes open gl tasks
void SetupRC()
        {
        HVel.x = 0.0f;
        HVel.y = 0.0f;
        HVel.z = 0.0f;
        //Resets some necessary values
        player.d = 0.0f;
        player.collision.back = false;
        player.collision.bottom = false;
        player.collision.front = false;
        player.collision.left = false;
        player.collision.right = false;
        player.collision.top = false;
        onfloor = true;

        //cameraFrame.RotateLocal(m3dDegToRad(-90.0f), 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);


        //Setup for level 1
        Level1();

    // Black background
    glClearColor(0.7f, 0.7f, 0.7f, 1.0f );

        //Starts the stock shaders
        shaderManager.InitializeStockShaders();

        //Enables depth filtering
        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

        //Sets up the transform pipeline
        transformPipeline.SetMatrixStacks(modelViewMatrix, projectionMatrix);

        //cameraFrame.MoveForward(-15.0f);

    // For Triangles, we'll make a Pyramid
        triangleBatch.Begin(GL_TRIANGLES, 12);
    triangleBatch.CopyVertexData3f(vPyramid);
    triangleBatch.End();

        playerBatch.Begin(GL_QUADS, 24);
        playerBatch.CopyVertexData3f(Playa);
        playerBatch.End();

        PlayerUpd(player.x, player.y, player.z);

    //That way there is some analytical things
        //Update();
    }
//Holds the field of view
float fov = 60.0f;
//Renders the scene every frame
void RenderScene(void)
        {    
                //Does all of the logic
                Update();
                // Clear the window with current clearing color
                glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);

                modelViewMatrix.PushMatrix();
                M3DMatrix44f mCamera;
                cameraFrame.GetCameraMatrix(mCamera);
                modelViewMatrix.MultMatrix(mCamera);

        M3DMatrix44f mObjectFrame;
        objectFrame.GetMatrix(mObjectFrame);
        modelViewMatrix.MultMatrix(mObjectFrame);

                //Enumerates so that all platforms can be drawn
                for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
                {
                        DrawWireFramedBatch(&Level[i], Collisions[i].c);
                }

                //Draws the batches
                //DrawWireFramedBatch(&triangleBatch);
                DrawWireFramedBatch(&QuadStrip, 1);

                modelViewMatrix.PopMatrix();
                glutPostRedisplay();

                //DrawWireFramedBatch(&playerBatch);


                // Flush drawing commands
                glutSwapBuffers();
                viewFrustum.SetPerspective(fov, 1.0f, 1.0f, 500.0);
                //Starts the lbox game basically keeping the last frames values
                player.lbox = player.box;
    } //Called to render the scene
//React to the changing screeen size, expecially changing the model view matrix
void ChangeSize(int w, int h)
        {
        //std::cout << SSTR( "GetBigger " << w << " , " << h << std::endl);
        width = w;
        height = h;
        glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
        viewFrustum.SetPerspective(fov, float(w) / float(h), 1.0f, 500.0f);
        projectionMatrix.LoadMatrix(viewFrustum.GetProjectionMatrix());
        modelViewMatrix.LoadIdentity();
        }
//Starts the glut process
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
        {
        gltSetWorkingDirectory(argv[0]);

        glutInit(&argc, argv);
        glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_STENCIL | GLUT_MULTISAMPLE);
        glutInitWindowSize(1000, 800);
        glutInitWindowPosition(700, 0);

        //Mouse stuff
        SetCursorPos((700 + 8 + ((1000/2) * 1)), (0 + -30 +  ((800/2) * 1)));

        glutCreateWindow("The Playground");
    glutReshapeFunc(ChangeSize);
    glutDisplayFunc(RenderScene);

        GLenum err = glewInit();
        if (GLEW_OK != err) {
                fprintf(stderr, "GLEW Error: %s\n", glewGetErrorString(err));
                return 1;
                }

        SetupRC();

        glutMainLoop();
        return 0;
        }
```

**PT2**
So I was trying to get things working properly as you said.  Unfortunately I have had a heck of a time "clearing" the transformation matrix as @Ethan said.  So I did some research on how to do this... And as it turns out I can do LoadIdentity(); on one of my matrix's.  HOwever when running the code it appears to do nothing.  ANyway here is my main rendering code (called every scene) could you try writing in the area that I commented that it draws the hud so that it all works out?  Here is the code

```
//Shader manager thing
GLShaderManager     shaderManager;
GLMatrixStack       modelViewMatrix;
GLMatrixStack       projectionMatrix;
//Camera translation things
GLFrame             cameraFrame;
//Object translation things
GLFrame             objectFrame;
GLFrustum           viewFrustum;
M3DMatrix44f        shadowMatrix;
GLGeometryTransform transformPipeline;

void RenderScene(void) 
    {    
        //Does all of the logic
        Update();
        // Clear the window with current clearing color
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);

        //I dont know whats going on in these couple lines
        modelViewMatrix.PushMatrix();
        M3DMatrix44f mCamera;
                    //cameraFrame does all the rotating and moving
        cameraFrame.GetCameraMatrix(mCamera);
        modelViewMatrix.MultMatrix(mCamera);

        M3DMatrix44f mObjectFrame;
        objectFrame.GetMatrix(mObjectFrame);
        modelViewMatrix.MultMatrix(mObjectFrame);



        //Draws all of the platforms stored inside of the array and passes what color they are
        for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
        {
            DrawWireFramedBatch(&Level[i], Collisions[i].c);
        }
        //Draws all of the dots.
        for (int p = 0; p < maxdots; p++)
        {
            if(Dots[p].active)
            {
                if (Dots[p].type == 1)
                {
                    //std::cout << "HI" << std::endl;
                    DrawWireFramedBatch(&Dotz[p], 8);
                }
            }
        }
        //I have no clue... fov stands for a variable that says fov
        viewFrustum.SetPerspective(fov, 1.0f, 0.0f, 200.0);

        //This is the batch I want to draw without any perspective....
        DrawWireFramedBatch(&bar1, 1); //CODE ON THIS LINE NEEDS NOT TO CARE ABOUT TRANSLATION SO THAT IT IS LIKE A HUD

        modelViewMatrix.PopMatrix();
        //Tells it to donother frame
        glutPostRedisplay();

        // Flush drawing commands
        glutSwapBuffers();

        //Starts the lbox game basically keeping the last frames values
        player.lbox = player.box;

    }
```

If not could you explain what some of these things are doing?

- 1. What is the difference between the ModelViewMatrix and the Projection
     Matrix?
- 2. What does LoadIdentity() do?
- 3. What does PushMatrix() do?
- 4. What does PopMatrix() do?
- 5. What is a Frustum (GLFrustum viewFrustum) do?

Answer (score 0):

Before answering your question, there are a few things that I would like to highlight:

- Your problem has absolutely nothing to do with Glew. Glew is simply a library that handle the loading of OpenGL functions/extensions.
- The way you use OpenGL is outdated and is no longer recommended. There are a few good modern tutorials that you should follow, using OpenGL 3 and above. Futhermore, you are mixing it with shader (?), which doesn't sound right.

Now, to your question. What you want to do is collectively term as GUI - Graphical User Interface. It is usually 2D that sits on top of everything. In order to draw such items, you will need to:

- First draw your 3D scene. Everything.
- Clear transformation matrices
- Draw the items you want (in this case is health bar).

Comment: Ok So I spent some time researching just how to clear transformation matrices.  I have been having the hardest time doing that... It isn't appearing to do anything.  I have put just my short rendering code in my original post could you please tell me how to clear the matrix properly? @Ethan

Comment: If you understand the stack data structure then the name of the functions glPushMatrix and glPopMatrix are pretty much self-explainatory. If you want to clear, simply pop all those you have pushed.

Comment: I am not familiar with what it means to pop or push a matrix @Ethan

Comment: http://www.swiftless.com/tutorials/opengl/pop_and_push_matrices.html. These are basic stuffs and Google is your friend.

Comment: alternatively, use loadIdentity to set the current matrix to identity (no transformation).

Comment: So if I used LoadIdentity it would be harder to undo what I did then if i pushed the matrix?

Comment: So theoretically to get this right I would have to push the  matrix, draw the thing, then pop it?

Comment: should I do this to both model and perspective matrix?